# comparing random variable sets to prove convergence in probability

Tags: statistics, asymptotics

Define a sequence of random variables $X_n$ whose distribution is given by $X_n\,=1$ with probability $n^{-1}$ and $X_n\,=0$ with probability $1-n^{-1}$. So, the claim is that $X_n$ converges in probability to 0. I can prove it using Markov's inequality as

For $\epsilon>0$, $P(|X_n-0|)\geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{E[|X_n|]}{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow0 $ as $n \rightarrow 0$.

In my class, my TA told me that the set $\{|Xn|>\epsilon\}\subset\{X_n=1\}$. So, she solved the problem like this:  $P\{|Xn|>\epsilon\}\subset P\{X_n=1\}=n^{-1}\rightarrow0$

I tried to understand why $\{|Xn|>\epsilon\}\subset\{X_n=1\}$ is possible. I asked her, and she just told me the events in $\{|Xn|>\epsilon\}$ are included in $\{X_n=1\}$. But still, I can't understand what she meant...

Could you please explain why that is possible??

Comment: Suppose $0 < \varepsilon <1$. Given that $X_n$ is either $1$ or $0$, if you know that $X_n > \varepsilon$ what do you know about $Xn$?

Comment: @Galton If $\epsilon$ is between 0 and 1, then $X_n>\epsilon$ is equivalent to $X_n=1$, right?

Comment: Yes, so it's not only an inclusion, it's an equality. We have $\{ |X_n| > \varepsilon \} = \{ X_n = 1 \}$ and therefore $P\{ |X_n| > \varepsilon \} = P\{ X_n = 1 \} = n^{-1}$. If $\varepsilon > 1$, then $\{ |X_n| > \varepsilon \}$ is empty and has probability zero, so there is nothing left to prove.

Comment: @Galton thanks! I can't understand why my TA said $\{ |X_n|>\epsilon\}$ is in $\{ X_n =1\}$

Comment: Because they are equal, you have both $\{|X_n| > \varepsilon\} \subset \{ X_n = 1 \}$ and $\{|X_n| > \varepsilon\} \supset \{ X_n = 1 \}$,  that's all.

Comment: @Galton it was easy.. THANKS A LOT! You save my life!